# Could not solve matching constructor - overriding BaseRepository Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-repositories

I am getting the Could not solve matching constructor error in an Interface and Class that extends BaseRepository.  I have rolled the code back to where I am only overriding the methods of the BaseRepository class and still cannot determine the cause.

Usually it is caused by something like two methods having the same name and Spring choosing the wrong one, but I don't see this happening.  The methods in UserPasswordResetToken were generated by the Eclipse IDE.  I selected all the classes to be implemented in the Right-click->source->Override/Implement Methods dialog.

Solutions I have seen online are specific in setting the constructor-arg value of the methods, but I am not using xml or java configuration for the UserPasswordResetToken class. I don't know where to declare  the constructor-arg values if I do make a bean config for it.  I could just code all of them, but that doesn't help me see the cause of the problem and learn about it. I also don't see where I have a two methods with the same name to confuse Spring.

I am one of those folks who not only wants the answer but also a way to avoid this in the future.  Any suggestions along that line would be helpful.  A revised error message saying which method is causing the problem would also be an improvement. Guess I have a suggestion for the Oracle folks.

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyExcep
tion: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceJPAConfig':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'env'; nested
exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name
'IUserVerificationTokenRepository': Could not resolve
matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name
arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
        at
io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(Deploy
mentManagerImpl.java:236)
        at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeployment
Service.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeployment
Service$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        ... 6 more
```

PersistenceJPAConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.aexample.persistence"},
    includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.aexample.persistence.*"))
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.aexample.persistence.repositories")
//@EnableJpaAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "dateTimeProvider")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public PersistenceJPAConfig() {
        super();
    }

    // beans
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.aexample.persistence.model" });

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass")));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry(){
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    final Properties additionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        // hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

}
```

IUserPasswordResetToken interface:

```
public interface IUserPasswordResetTokenRepository extends BaseRepository<UserPasswordResetToken, Long> {


    void delete(UserPasswordResetToken token);

    public List<UserPasswordResetToken> findAll();

    public UserPasswordResetToken findOne(Long id);

    public UserPasswordResetToken save(UserPasswordResetToken persisted);

    UserPasswordResetToken findByToken(String token);

    UserPasswordResetToken findByUser(User user);

    Stream<UserPasswordResetToken> findAllByExpiryDateLessThan(Date now);

    void deleteByExpiryDateLessThan(Date now);

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from UserPasswordResetToken t where t.expiryDate <= ?1")
    void deleteAllExpiredSince(Date now);
}
```

UserPasswordResetToken Class:

```
public abstract class UserPasswordResetTokenRepositoryImpl implements IUserPasswordResetTokenRepository {

    private IUserPasswordResetTokenRepository repository;


    /**
     * @param repository
     */
    public UserPasswordResetTokenRepositoryImpl(IUserPasswordResetTokenRepository repository) {
        super();
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(UserPasswordResetToken deleted) {

        repository.delete(deleted);

    }

    @Override
    public List<UserPasswordResetToken> findAll() {

        List<UserPasswordResetToken> theTokens = repository.findAll();

        return theTokens;
    }

    @Override
    public UserPasswordResetToken findOne(Long id) {

        UserPasswordResetToken theToken = repository.findOne(id);

        return theToken;
    }

    @Override
    public UserPasswordResetToken save(UserPasswordResetToken persisted) {

        UserPasswordResetToken theToken = repository.save(persisted);

        return theToken;

    }

    @Override
    public UserPasswordResetToken findByToken(String token) {

        UserPasswordResetToken theToken = repository.findByToken(token);

        return theToken;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<UserPasswordResetToken> findAllByExpiryDateLessThan(Date now) {

        Stream<UserPasswordResetToken> theTokenStream = repository.findAllByExpiryDateLessThan(now);

        return theTokenStream;

    }

    @Override
    public UserPasswordResetToken findByUser(User user) {

        UserPasswordResetToken theToken = repository.findByUser(user);

        return theToken;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteByExpiryDateLessThan(Date now) {

        repository.deleteByExpiryDateLessThan(now);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllExpiredSince(Date now) {

        repository.deleteAllExpiredSince(now);

    }

}
```

BaseRepository Class

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;


@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID>{

    void delete(T deleted);

    List<T> findAll();

    T findOne(ID id);

    T save(T persisted);    

}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where the BaseRepository.class comes from, or is it your implementation. If it's your implementation please post the code.

Comment: Ah, good point.  Code is posted.  It extends the springframework. data.repository class.  So yes, I have interfaces extending interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

HOLD ON...I am confusing myself.  I just reread the stack trace.  I was working on the IUserPasswordTokenRepository Class but the stack trace now reads **IUserVerificationTokenRepositoryClass**.  I fixed the PasswordToken class and did not notice it!

I previously had two methods for delete, one with string and one token params.  I deleted the String one and reran everything.  I did not notice the Class name had changed in the stack trace as they are similarly named.  So I did see the problem after all.

Thanks for looking!